# Visual Studio Code / powershell commands History up key

Tags: powershell, command-line, visual-studio-code

In what way could I log my previously entered commands in visual studio code?
For instance when I press up key I can up through all my previous commands,
I would like to log these to a file if possible.

Where are they stored locally?
Could I log it with something like node?

Comment: You want to log only cmdlet history or would [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) do the trick?

Comment: I would like to log the history, have looked at Start/Stop transcript, good call though! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've actually solved this myself thanks to the help of @bruce-payette and @robdy for pointing me in new directions. Logging all commands, also from previous sessions, can be done from PowerShell itself.
Enter this command in PowerShell to recieve the path to a file where PowerShell saves the history accessible by using the up key:

```
(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

This will output something like this:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

Open this file to see all saved commands from previous sessions!

Comment: also note that `$PROFILE` is in a different path for the Pwsh extension. If you place your profile in `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` it will share it for  both

Answer (score 2):

The cmdlet `Get-History` will give you the history of the commands you've run. You can save this to a file by doing

```
Get-History | Out-File myhistory.txt
```

Comment: Yeah that output's my history from this session perfect, thanks @bruce-payette! Do you know if there is a way to get the cmds from older sessions? I.E. i keep pressing up and see older commands, but the output file contains 1 entry from the current sesh..