# Dedicated Command History panel in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd find it convenient to be able to quickly recall past commands issued in the terminal. In Matlab  one can simply select any number of those from the Command HIstory panel, and reissue them in the Terminal all at once:

[image]

In VS Code (on Windows), I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942294/1853284) there is a command to pull up the log text file:

```
(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

But I find this extremely cumbersome as a solution to call up multiple lines at a time. Is there an VS Code addon that creates a Matlab-like Command History panel with timestamped commands (didn't find any searching myself)? Or is such feedback taken into consideration by Microsoft?

Comment: Please don't tag Visual Studio for a Visual Studio Code question

Comment: The terminal in VS Code is (usually) Powershell. Perhaps you should be looking for a Powershell solution?!

Comment: Or perhaps if you have a common set of commands you run, did you consider writing a Powershell script?

Comment: @phuzi sorry - fixed

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about Powershell, I am not an advanced user and was simply wondering how to have a Command History panel. Since there's no addon for it, filing a feedback ticket with MS seems the way to go

Answer (score 2):

See [v1.70 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#run-recent-command-as-a-replacement-for-reverse-search):

Triggering the `Terminal: Run Recent Command...` will bring up a QuickPick panel of recent terminal commands in which you can search, fuzzy or not, through the recent commands.

There are some examples of commands for going to the next item in the list, for example.

See the supported shells and OS's mentioned below.  I believe it is still accurate.  Git Bash on Windows doesn't work with this new recent command functionality, but powershell does.  Support for MacOS and linux is stronger: bash, powershell and zsh.

And see [v1.69 release notes: run recent command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#run-recent-command):

> Some other functionality of the command:
>
> In the current session section, there is a clipboard icon in the right
> of the Quick Pick that will open the command output in an editor. Alt
> can be held to write the text to the terminal without running it. The
> amount of history stored in the previous session section is determined
> by the `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.history` setting.
>
> There is currently no keybinding assigned by default but it can be
> hooked up to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for example with the
> following keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+space",    // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runRecentCommand",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

This might help (coming to v1.64):

> ##### Terminal shell integration
>
> The terminal now features experimental opt-in shell integration which
> allows VS Code to gain insights on what is going on within the
> terminal as it was previously a black box. When enabled using
> `"terminal.integrated.enableShellIntegration": true`, arguments to run
> a shell integration script will be injected into your terminal profile
> if possible. The script itself mostly just injects invisible sequences
> into your prompt, providing us with information like where the prompt,
> command and command output is, what the current working directory
> (`cwd`) is for each command and the exit code of each command.
>
> Shell integration enables the following new features:
>
> Run recent command: Since we know what commands are run, we have
> exposed a command that allows you to view and run them again in a
> quick pick.

`Developer: Run Recent Command`  run this command from the Command Palette

[image: run recent command image]

> The current shells supported are `pwsh` for Windows and `pwsh`, `bash` and
> `zsh` for Linux and macOS.

- from [release notes: terminal shell integration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#terminal-shell-integration)

Although I switched to powerShell on W11 to test this feature - which should be supported - I can't get it to work just now.  I wanted to see if you could pick multiple command entries in the QuickPick to run a series of them, but I doubt you can.  But at least you get a nice list of recent commands.

Comment: Of interest, in VSCode 1.70: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155871